# how to remove watermark of pdfjs-express

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used pdfjs-express as a pdf viewer in react.js project.
I want to remove watermark of pdfjs-express.
I tried to add a free license key of a specific domain and use viewer package, but it doesn't remove watermark.

Do you know how to remove it?
Thank you!

Comment: it looks like you need to buy a copy.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
But I can't see the watermark on free version demo.